# Operator overloading doesn't work

Tags: c++

I'm making a matrix3x3 class, and although I have the required functionality thereof the operator overloading as to `*=`, `+=`, `-=` and `/=` don't work. Here's what I have:

```
mat3 operator*(const mat3 &m); // Declared within mat3 class

mat3 mat3::operator *=(const mat3& m) // How it's implemented
{
    *this = *this * m;
    return *this;
}
```

Suffice it to say, that it kinda works; but this is the usage I want:

```
mat3 m; // Initialise to identity matrix

m *= mat3(2.0); // Multiply matrix by scalar and apply
```

The problem is that it doesn't affect the matrix at all! `m` remains the same, even though I've just done a `*= mat3(2.0)` operation on it. However, this works:

```
m = m *= mat3(2.0);
```

Which is just silly, because I might as well do:

```
m = m * mat3(2.0);
```

The whole point is that all the above multiplications **MUST** return the same result. There's no approximations nor compromise here. Quite frankly, all the operators pertaining to `*=`, `+=` etc do not work. How can I get this kind of operator overload working such that multiplying a matrix and applying that multiplication can be done as easy as:

```
m *= mat3(2.0)
```

Comment: write operator * in terms of operator *=. You've got it the wrong way around.

Comment: Think of what this returns: `mat3 mat3::operator *=(const mat3& m)`. Then read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: @RichardHodges Can you explain?

Comment: Your `operator*=` looks fine (though it would be better to return by reference).  The problem must be in some code not shown here.

Comment: How does `2` match `const mat3& m` ?

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't think that advice applies to matrix multiplication, which is not easily done "in place".

Comment: `m *= 2;` shouldn't compile unless you have a converting constructor, which seems nonsensical.

Comment: I'd guess that your copy-assignment operator or copy-constructor is not implemented properly. To get good answers, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I corrected the confusion by editing my post.

Comment: Change the return type `mat3& mat3::operator *=(const mat3& m)`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I solved the issue. I don't know how I solved it, but I know I didn't use a screw driver this time!